# sqs boto3: The address 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/xxxx/my-name' is not valid for this endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm having a very hard time trying to find out how to correctly configure sqs in boto3 to be able to send messages to my sqs queue. It looks like there is some confusion around boto3 and legacy endpoints but I'm getting the error message `The address 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/xxxx/my-name' is not valid for this endpoint.` for each permutation of the config I can imagine. Here's the code.

```
# Tried both of these
sqs_queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx/my-queue'
sqs_queue_url = 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/xxxx/my-queue'

# Tried both of these 
sqs = boto3.client("sqs", endpoint_url="https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
sqs = boto3.client("sqs")

# _endpoint updates
logger.info("sqs endpoint: %s", sqs._endpoint)

# Keeps failing
sqs.send_message(QueueUrl=sqs_queue_url, MessageBody=message_json)
```

I'm hoping this is a silly mistake. What config am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct code? This is invalid python. You are missing quotes are your urls, endpoint_url is incorrect.

Comment: I just pasted it wrong, I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sqs-service.html#sqs_region), AWS CLI and Python SDK use **legacy endpoints**:

> If you use the AWS CLI or **SDK for Python**, you can use the following legacy endpoints.

Also, when you set endpoint you need to **add https**:

```
sqs = boto3.client("sqs", endpoint_url="https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com")
```

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing in the example, unless I'm misreading. I am using https as well, I'll update my original line.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo The original code of yours did not have https. Your endpoint is a new one, not legacy. I also made mistake in my answer. Updated to legacy endpoint now. Sorry.

Comment: The implication is that I should manually reformat my queue url to use the same domain as this legacy endpoint url?

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo No. The endpoint and the queue url are two different things.